# Write Consistency in horizontally scalable in Web Applications

Tags: java, web-applications, concurrency, scalability

I've been working with web applications for quite some time now. However, I've never worked on web applications that are hosted as multiple instances and are load balanced.

My question: How do web applications manage writes across several instances of same application?

For eg: a ticket booking site. Imagine I block seats in a certain row for a movie and submit my request. At the same time another user (served by other instance by virtue of application being clustered and load balanced) also blocked one of the seats that I have selected, how do web applications manage this scenario? Since, they are different processes running on different machines where does locking happen? How do they maintain cache consistency? Are there any solutions readily available?

Comment: What is your backend? Do you use database? Which?

Comment: @Tichodroma. We are not switching to load balanced app anytime soon. I'm interested in this academically. Still, I'm familiar with locking and transaction isolation levels in SQL Server, Spring Transaction management and JBoss cache. With this background of mine if you can point me to some articles that can enhance my understanding of distributed apps, I'll be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you still get the same issue with concurrent writes in a single-node application, it's just easier to manage them since it's one JVM.

> Since, they are different processes running on different machines where does locking happen?

Database, being single point shared by all instances, is the easiest goal. Depending on your expected load and use cases, [*optimistic locking*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_locking) is very easy to achieve ([example in JPA](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/caroljmcdonald/archive/2009/07/jpa_20_concurre.html)). Combined with database transactions, you achieve certain level of atomicity without trading performance.

> How do they maintain cache consistency? Are there any solutions readily available?

Caching is hard, especially in distributed environment. For instance [ehcache](/questions/tagged/ehcache) can communicate between instances and once cache changes in one instance, it broadcasts this event to other nodes. There are plenty of other products like [terracotta](/questions/tagged/terracotta), [hazelcast](/questions/tagged/hazelcast), etc.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Can you share some blog posts how optimistic locking is achieved?

Comment: @Gopal: I added few links to my answer

Comment: Tomasz Nurkiewicz..thanks for the answer. I was revisiting the question yesterday and your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I worked for some years on a ticket booking backend. Typically, in that scenario, the whole web app is backed by a database, and seats have different states: available, blocked, booked.

Here's how it worked:

- Users A and B enter the webapp, both see that seat S is available.
- User A selects seat S. In the database, the state for S changes from `available` to `booked`
- User B tries to select seat S. Backend replies that seat S is `blocked`, and user B sees an error message.

You could make your app more user-friendly by updating the seat status 'live', using Ajax for example.